# Specifying Order of Inclusion of Items in SQL Server Data Tools Project

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

Visual Studio 2019 w/ SQL Server Data Tools on Windows 10, Target DB = SQL Server 2019

How do you control the order within which elements are included in Publish?

For example, I have some scripts elements that create the schemas, and then script elements that define tables in those schemas. When I publish the generated sql (1) only includes some of the .sql files (even though they are marked as Build in their properties) and (2) it just seems to do a lot of the stuff alphabetically (e.g, putting schema creation script AFTER a table that uses it).

Tried: turning build property on and off. No error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control the order by default. You can do that by developing your own deployment contributor, but normally you don't need that. SSDT should handle all these normally.

If some objects are not deployed, then they probably are excluded in the publish profile. Review all your settings for publish profile and make sure that certain objects are not excluded.

Comment: Thanks that was the solution. Why doesn't Microsoft promote this tool more? It's really terrific.

Comment: could you please rename the question to something like: